# How to filter an array and get the filtered length?

Tags: java, jsonpath

Use the typical json as an example:

```
{ "store": {
    "book": [
      { "category": "reference",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",
        "price": 8.95
      },
      { "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 12.99
      },
      { "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Herman Melville",
        "title": "Moby Dick",
        "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
        "price": 8.99
      },
      { "category": "fiction",
        "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
        "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
        "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
        "price": 22.99
      }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
      "color": "red",
      "price": 19.95
    }
  }
}
```

I want filter the books, and get the filter result array size.

I write the json path as:  $..book[?(@.category in ['fiction'])].size()

The expected value is 3.
But actually I got 14.

Tried $..book[?(@.category in ['fiction'])].length()

Still got same result: 14

Comment: The `length()` function has some flaws. Try out if this works for you `$.length($.store.book[?(@.category=="fiction")].length())`.  Tested here https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/?path=$.length($.store.book[?(@.category%20==%20%22fiction%22)].length())

Comment: Thank you. @AkshayG, It works. How can I set your answer as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.store.book[?(@.category=="fiction")].length()

//Output
[
   4,
   5,
   5
]
```

will give the count of properties in each book. This is the reason you are getting 14 (4+5+5) for `$..book[?(@.category == "fiction")].length()`

Now, if you use the length function on the resulting array, you will get 3 which is the desired result.

```
$.length($.store.book[?(@.category == "fiction")].length())
```

Try here : [Jayway JsonPath Evaluator](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/?path=$.length($.store.book%5B?(@.category%20==%20%22fiction%22)%5D.length()))

This is a work-around for your requirement, There are many open issues with similar questions in the github [length() not working as expected](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/562)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use something like this:

```
int count = 0;
for (Book book : store) {
  count = book.category.equals('fiction')? count+1 : count;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. We are using jsonpath to develop a tool for testing. this method is used for a common method to get a value of the specified json path. So we cannot use this method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
$..book[?(@.category=="fiction")]
```

Many examples in:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath

The full js code:

```
'use strict';
const $ = require( "jquery" );
const fs = require('fs');
var jp = require('jsonpath');

var store = { "store": {
    "book": [
      { "category": "reference",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",
        "price": 8.95
      },
      { "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 12.99
      },
      { "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Herman Melville",
        "title": "Moby Dick",
        "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
        "price": 8.99
      },
      { "category": "fiction",
        "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
        "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
        "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
        "price": 22.99
      }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
      "color": "red",
      "price": 19.95
    }
  }
};
var book = store["store"]
var len = jp.query(book, '$..book[?(@.category=="fiction")]').length
console.debug(len)
```

Comment: Hi, Use $..book[?(@.category=="fiction")].size(), still got 14.

Comment: This yields 3:
jp.query(book, '$..book[?(@.category=="fiction")]').length

Comment: I have updated my answer with the full js code.

Comment: Thank you. But I am using java now.